# Is max storage capacity of Heroku free apps more than 3GB?

Tags: heroku, storage, free

My Heroku app has more that 3gb storage capacity and i want to is it true?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I9wt.png)
based of Heroku site it must have 500MB as you could see [here](https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup#quota) :

> Heroku has certain soft and hard limits in using its service. Hard
>   limits are automatically enforced by the Service. Soft limits are
>   consumable resources that you agree not to exceed.
>
> > ```
> > Network Bandwidth: 2TB/month - Soft
> > Shared DB processing: Max 200msec per second CPU time - Soft
> > Dyno RAM usage: Determined by Dyno type - Hard
> > Slug Size: 500MB - Hard
> > Request Length: 30 seconds - Hard
> > ```

Excuse me, I googled [**free dyno max storage size**](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=y52&channel=fs&sxsrf=ACYBGNTB1m-LMf63DKj6MTHhcYtZ_9O6zQ%3A1574791397476&ei=5WjdXYTYHJDasAeh_L7oDg&q=free%20dyno%20max%20storage%20size&oq=free%20dyno%20max%20storage%20size&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.175651.178676..178823...0.0..0.575.6718.3-2j5j7......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j33i22i29i30.QLnrdPs4348&ved=0ahUKEwjE3t2Ou4jmAhUQLewKHSG-D-0Q4dUDCAo&uact=5) but I get some sites [like this](https://www.heroku.com/dynos) which have not information about the max capacity of the Heroku free apps!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLqFD.png)

I must add that someone else  added the **my.sassy.girl.s1.web.48-pahe.in** file in this rapidly site and I don't know is its size is really 3 GB (but when I trying download it the Firefox browser show it's size in 3 GB), any idea to find out is the size of that file is really 3GB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 MB limit is that of [the slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) - the code and other assets in your Git repository that you're deploying.

Heroku dynos also have temporary storage you can utilize, but it's important to note that any files placed on these dynos **disappears after any dyno reboot**. That means every 24 hours (as well as after any deployment) your files not in your Git repository *will all go away*.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

User-uploaded files should go to static storage like Amazon S3.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: Side note: Using Heroku dynos for torrenting will probably get you quickly banned.

Comment: Thanks but i don't get the max storage capacity size!!

Comment: @modern That's temporary storage available to your app. How much is available probably varies based on the dyno size. Again, it's **temporary** and will be purged at least once every 24 hours.